# How to access a javascript function inside an ajax request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a javascript function:

```
function test () {
    alert('test');
}
```

Then, I am making an ajax request:

```
$.post('myPath', 
    function (response) {
        test();
    }, "json");
    return false;
}
```

But the test function is not available there.

Here is the full code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function () {
        function test () {
            alert('test');
        }

        $.post('myPath', 
            function (response) {
                test();
            }, "json"); 

            return false;
        }
</script>
```

Comment: Im guessing the function is out of scope...can't tell without seeing the position of both functions in the code

Comment: Post the full code, the function is probably out of the ajax request's scope.

Comment: @Milos based on your edit, there is nothing wrong with the code in the question, it is syntactically and logically sound, and `test()` is in scope. What error are you seeing? Is jQuery included?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. Might work. But not sure.

```
var test;//global
window.onload = function() {
  test=function() {
     alert('test');
  }

  $.post('myPath', 
       function(response){
          test();
      }, "json"); 

      return false;
  }
}
```

or

```
var test=function() {
     alert('test');
  }

window.onload = function() {

  $.post('myPath', 
       function(response){
          test();
      }, "json"); 

      return false;
  }
}
```